# How to prevent react rerendering when switching routes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to prevent rerendering my `SideBarLink` React component.
I am calling `SideBarLink` component from `SideBar`, which runs a loop and renders each route.
I undestand that it renders the number of times as the size of the `SIDEBAR_LINKS` array when the page loads the first time. But I am trying to prevent it from redering multiple times when I am just switching the route.
This is my `SideBarLink` Component,

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { SideBarRouteLink } from "../../modules/Routes/SideBarRoutes";

const linkClass =
  "flex items-center gap-2 font-light px-3 py-2 hover:text-white hover:font-bold rounded-sm text-base";

interface SideBarLinkProps {
  link: SideBarRouteLink;
}

const SideBarLink: React.FC<SideBarLinkProps> = ({ link }) => {
  console.log("SideBarLink");

  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <Link
      to={link.path}
      className={classNames(
        "flex items-center relative",
        pathname === link.path ? "text-white font-bold" : "text-slate-100",
        linkClass
      )}
    >
      {pathname === link.path && (
        <span className="absolute top-1/2 left-0 transform -translate-y-1/2 w-1 h-6 bg-white"></span>
      )}
      <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
        <span className="text-xl">
          <link.icon />
        </span>
        <span>{link.label}</span>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default SideBarLink;
```

This is my `SideBar` Component which renders the `SideBarLink` component.

```
import React from "react";
import { SIDEBAR_LINKS } from "../../modules/Routes/SideBarRoutes";
import SideBarLink from "./SideBarLink";

const SideBarView: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("SideBar VIEEEW");

  return (
    <div className="bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-600 to-cyan-400 w-60 p-3 flex flex-col">
      <div className="flex gap-2 justify-center px-1 py-8">
        <span className="font-medium leading-10 tracking-widest text-white text-2xl">
          KAROOOBAR
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className="border-t-2 border-b-2 border-gray-100 py-4 text-center">
        <h1 className="text-base text-white">Sample Store</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-0.5 py-8 ">
        {SIDEBAR_LINKS.map((link) => (
          <SideBarLink key={link.key} link={link} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 px-3">
        <a
          href="mailto:karooobar@gmail.com"
          className="font-light text-white text-sm"
        >
          karooobar@gmail.com
        </a>
        <p className="font-light text-white text-sm">© 2023, Karooobar Inc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBarView;
```

ANd this is my SideBarRouteLink array,

```
export const SIDEBAR_LINKS: SideBarRouteLink[] = [
  {
    key: "home",
    label: "Home",
    path: "/",
    icon: MdOutlineHome,
  },
  {
    key: "register",
    label: "Register",
    path: "/register",
    icon: GiArchiveRegister,
  },
  {
    key: "reports",
    label: "Reports",
    path: "/reports",
    icon: HiOutlineDocumentText,
  },
  {
    key: "support",
    label: "Help & Support",
    path: "/support",
    icon: HiOutlineQuestionMarkCircle,
  },
];
```

How can I fix this to only render once when switching the route. If it is not possible what will be the better way to define routes. I really like defining them in a separate file.

I tried using React Memo like this in the `SideBarLink` component but it didn't work,

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { SideBarRouteLink } from "../../modules/Routes/SideBarRoutes";

const linkClass =
  "flex items-center gap-2 font-light px-3 py-2 hover:text-white hover:font-bold rounded-sm text-base";

interface SideBarLinkProps {
  link: SideBarRouteLink;
}

const SideBarLink: React.FC<SideBarLinkProps> = React.memo(
  ({ link }) => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    console.log("sidebar link");

    return (
      <Link
        to={link.path}
        className={classNames(
          "flex items-center relative",
          pathname === link.path ? "text-white font-bold" : "text-slate-100",
          linkClass
        )}
      >
        {pathname === link.path && (
          <span className="absolute top-1/2 left-0 transform -translate-y-1/2 w-1 h-6 bg-white"></span>
        )}
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <span className="text-xl">
            <link.icon />
          </span>
          <span>{link.label}</span>
        </div>
      </Link>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return prevProps.link === nextProps.link;
  }
);

SideBarLink.displayName = "SideBarLink";

export default SideBarLink;
```

Thank you

Comment: can you also provide the place where you are using your sidebar view?

Comment: Code sandbox would help to handle this issue

Comment: Sidebar view is used in the App component